# Spring Batch File Archiving

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

i am currently in process of learning spring batch and i have been challenged with a task of file archiving. Basically i need to read separate CSV files and put them in a new archived folder with the original filename appended with the current date. What i want to know is how i can get the original filename from the multiResourceItemReader, use it in the FlatfileItemWriter as the filename + date and deleting the original file afterwards.

Here's my current code:

```
@Autowired
public JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

@Autowired
public StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

@Value("classpath*:/data/CSV_FOR_ARCHIVING*.csv")
private Resource inputFiles[];

@Bean
public MultiResourceItemReader<Person> multiResourceItemReader() {
    MultiResourceItemReader<Person> itemReader = new MultiResourceItemReader<>();

    itemReader.setDelegate(personItemReader());
    itemReader.setResources(inputFiles);

    return itemReader;
}

@Bean
public FlatFileItemReader<Person> personItemReader() {
    FlatFileItemReader<Person> itemReader = new FlatFileItemReader<>();

    itemReader.setLinesToSkip(1);

    DefaultLineMapper<Person> personLineMapper = new DefaultLineMapper<>();

    DelimitedLineTokenizer tokenizer = new DelimitedLineTokenizer();
    tokenizer.setNames(new String[] { "id", "firstName", "lastName", "email", "gender" });

    personLineMapper.setLineTokenizer(tokenizer);
    personLineMapper.setFieldSetMapper(new PersonFieldSetMapper());
    personLineMapper.afterPropertiesSet();

    itemReader.setLineMapper(personLineMapper);

    return itemReader;
}

@Bean
public FlatFileItemWriter<Person> jsonWriter() throws Exception {
    FlatFileItemWriter<Person> personWriter = new FlatFileItemWriter<>();

    personWriter.setLineAggregator(new PersonLineAggregator());
    File outputPath = File.createTempFile("PersonOutput", ".csv", new File("C:/Users/default/Documents"));
    System.out.println("Output Path: " + outputPath.getAbsolutePath());

    personWriter.setResource(new FileSystemResource(outputPath));
    personWriter.afterPropertiesSet();

    return personWriter;
}

@Bean
public Step step1() throws Exception {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1").<Person, Person>chunk(10)
            .listener(new ItemReaderListener())
            .reader(multiResourceItemReader())
            .writer(jsonWriter())
            .build();
}

@Bean
public Job job() throws Exception {
    return jobBuilderFactory.get("job")
            .start(step1())
            .build();
}
```

[CSV files to be readed and archived separately](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6P3Sm.png)

EDIT 1: 
Thanks for the answer @Niraj, i've implemented the ResourceAware and i can already get the filename. Now my new question is how do i tell my FlatFileItemWriter to create and write on a new file each time the resource has changed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring batch-Delete the flatfile from directory after processed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23323535/spring-batch-delete-the-flatfile-from-directory-after-processed)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use ResourceAware interface to get the current file name. And ResourceSuffixCreator interface to create suffix as per you need

http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/ResourceAware.html
http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/file/ResourceSuffixCreator.html

Comment: Thank you for the answer i implemented this already and now i have a new question. I want the flatfileitemwriter to use this 'resource' as the filename for the output file. Also how do i make my flatfileitemwriter write a new output file each time the resource filename is changed?

Comment: in order to have new output file each time  , you need to set chunkSize as 1

Answer (score 0):

You can put the value in executionContext from your reader and read in your writer. Something like this

```
  @Value("#{jobExecution.executionContext}")
  private ExecutionContext executionContext;

  public void somePlaceInYourReader(){
      this.executionContext.putInt("fileName", fileName);
  }
```

And read it the same way using `executionContext.getInt("fileName")`.  You might have to use this as well [@JobScope](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/configuration/annotation/JobScope.html)